# Updating Parse.com SDK through CocoaPods using iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, cocoapods

Trying to add and update a CocoaPod that is used in my application.

Unfortunately I got the following error while adding or updating the pods:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Parse` required by `Podfile`
- `Parse (= 1.4.2)` required by `Podfile.lock`
- `Parse (~> 1.4.1)` required by `ParseFacebookUtils (1.4.1)`
- `Parse (~> 1.6)` required by `ParseUI (1.1.0)`
```

Comment: Try to remove all references to Parse from your podfile, and then rund 'pod install' to uninstall it. When finished, add the correct references to Parse again, and run 'pod install' once more.

Answer (score 0):

Parse Quick Srart

https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing

Add pod 'Parse' to your podfile and run pod install.

u can run: pod install --verbose --no-repo-update

Comment: i know how to integrate parse , my Question is different  i am getting the following error's while installing parse through cocoa pod

Comment: what's the version of CocoaPods on your mac? u can try update your CocoaPods.

Comment: my Podfile content is only: pod 'Parse'